# iTextSharp Valid License Not working

Tags: c#, .net, itext, itext7

I'm trying to use iTextSharp with valid license obtained for commercial purpose.
But the document producer line is still showing "AGPL version".

Steps Followed:

1. Installed iText 7 License Key (dll version 2.0.2.0) and iTextSharp (dll version 5.5.10.0) through Nuget
2. Loaded the license XML file before generating the PDF.

   ```
   LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile(path\iTextkey.xml);
   ```

After loading the license file, I'm able to see the name, company , key etc. details in `LicenseKey.GetLicenseeInfo()`.

PDF Producer still shows iText Group NV (AGPL-version) instead of Licensed.

[image: PDF Document Properties]

Any suggestions on why it is not working?

Comment: You have to download it from `nuget packager`

Comment: yes.. downloaded from nuget package only

Comment: As you are an iText customer, why don't you simply ask their support? And are you sure an "iText 7 License Key" can be used for "iTextSharp 5.5.10.0"?

Comment: What @mkl said. You need the iText 5 license DLL for licensing iTextSharp 5, just [as their license key page says](http://developers.itextpdf.com/license-key-download).

Comment: Also, if you're a commercial user, then you should ask this type of question on the customer ticketing system. There's no need to muddy up SO for something that is clearly something in-house support should handle.

Comment: I am upvoting this question, in case other people are mixing wrong versions of iText and license keys.

Comment: @user7121382 if you agree with the answer below, then please accept it.

Comment: @user7121382 I am still waiting for you to accept my answer.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse according to the user's profile, he was *Last seen Dec 17 '16 at 10:19*. Thus, I would not hope for any reaction by him ever, let alone any time soon...

Comment: Hit&run accounts... *cringe*

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing the wrong versions of iText and the License Key library.

- iText **5** for .NET (aka iTextSharp) requires License Key library **1**.0.4. Available only on the iText website.
- iText **7** for .NET requires License Key library **2**.0.2. Available on NuGet and on the iText website.

See also http://developers.itextpdf.com/license-key-download